# Range sort failure with Google spreadsheet (multiple editors)

Tags: permissions, google-apps-script

I have the following script working to sort a shared spreadsheet by date & time.

```
function onOpen(event){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var tableRange = "A2:O";
  var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
  range.sort( [1, 3] );
  }
```

The script runs fine when I open the spreadsheet, but I received a failure notification from when another collaborator was using the spreadsheet. The error was: *You don't have permission for this action (line 7, file "Code")*. Is there some way to make sure every collaborator has the necessary permissions for the script to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that each user of the spreadsheet had to authorize the spreadsheet to use an onOpen trigger. I switched to using a time-based trigger.